# Optimize javascript function code if ... else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, if-statement

I implemented a logic that forces me to create many conditions based on different properties value. At first i thought i could refactor it with `switch ... case` statements but as it does not depend on a single value, i can't go for this solution.

If it were you, how would be optimize, maintain this code ?
context: We are in a React Component, so maybe i could also use `useCallback` or `UseMemo` ?

```
function navigateToNextStep() {
    if (
      user.lifecycle.stepCompany === 'todo' ||
      user.lifecycle.stepCompany === 'progress'
    ) {
      navigation.navigate(App.SETUP.COMPANY);
    }
    if (
      user.lifecycle.stepIdentity === 'todo' ||
      user.lifecycle.stepIdentity === 'progress'
    ) {
      navigation.navigate(App.SETUP.IDENTITY);
    }
    if (user.lifecycle.stepFinalize === 'todo') {
      navigation.navigate(App.SETUP.FINALIZE);
    }
    if (user.lifecycle.stepIdentity === 'awaiting_review') {
      navigation.navigate(App.SETUP.MODAL.AWAITING_REVIEW);
    }
    if (user.lifecycle.stepIdentity === 'need_approval') {
      navigation.navigate(App.SETUP.MODAL.APPROVAL_REQUIRED);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ifs are easier to read than anything else in this case. Anyway, code review is off topic for SO

Comment: You may ask for advice here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: nothing much you can do with that. but it may look better if you assign each condition to a variable and then use them in your function. this way you'll have a cleaner and more understandable function

Comment: `const shouldSetupCompany = user.lifecycle.stepCompany === 'todo' || user.lifecycle.stepCompany === 'progress'` there you go. Now the intention of the code is clearly labelled and it's thus easier to maintain and reason about.

Comment: I'd turn it into a series of if/else, so you could add a final check for when `user.lifecycle.stepIdentity` doesn't match any of the currently expected values.  Other than that, it's easy to read and understand, and there are no performance issues; what is your goal in "optimizing" this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have quite complicated if-else statements take a look at [RulesEngine](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/RulesEngine.html),

> This is a set of production rules, each of which has a condition and an action - simplistically you can think of it as a bunch of if-then statements.

maybe in your case, it's the best way to simplify(but in most cases, if-else or switch-case enough).

Here you can find different [implementations for js](https://npm.io/search/keyword:rules+engine).
Take a look at [json-rules-engine](https://github.com/cachecontrol/json-rules-engine) as an example:

> This example demonstates an engine for identifying employees who work for Microsoft and are taking Christmas day off.

```js
const { Engine } = require('json-rules-engine')


/**
 * Setup a new engine
 */
let engine = new Engine()

// define a rule for detecting the player has exceeded foul limits.  Foul out any player who:
// (has committed 5 fouls AND game is 40 minutes) OR (has committed 6 fouls AND game is 48 minutes)
engine.addRule({
  conditions: {
    any: [{
      all: [{
        fact: 'gameDuration',
        operator: 'equal',
        value: 40
      }, {
        fact: 'personalFoulCount',
        operator: 'greaterThanInclusive',
        value: 5
      }]
    }, {
      all: [{
        fact: 'gameDuration',
        operator: 'equal',
        value: 48
      }, {
        fact: 'personalFoulCount',
        operator: 'greaterThanInclusive',
        value: 6
      }]
    }]
  },
  event: {  // define the event to fire when the conditions evaluate truthy
    type: 'fouledOut',
    params: {
      message: 'Player has fouled out!'
    }
  }
})

/**
 * Define facts the engine will use to evaluate the conditions above.
 * Facts may also be loaded asynchronously at runtime; see the advanced example below
 */
let facts = {
  personalFoulCount: 6,
  gameDuration: 40
}

// Run the engine to evaluate
engine
  .run(facts)
  .then(({ events }) => {
    events.map(event => console.log(event.params.message))
  })

/*
 * Output:
 *
 * Player has fouled out!
 */
```

---

Or you can write a simple implementation of Rule Engine based on Object on your own.

As an example for your case:

```js
const rules = [{
    rule: (user) => ['todo', 'progress'].includes(user.lifecycle.stepCompany),
    action: () => console.log("App.SETUP.COMPANY")
  },
  {
    rule: (user) => ['todo', 'progress'].includes(user.lifecycle.stepIdentity),
    action: () => console.log("App.SETUP.IDENTITY")
  }
]

const user = {
  lifecycle: {
    stepCompany: 'todo',
    stepIdentity: 'progress'
  }
}

rules.forEach(r => {
  if (r.rule(user)) {
    r.action()
  }
})
```